# Azure Search space issue?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Need help, when I type "Bob Johnson" without space it does not give exact match however when I type "Bob Johnson " with space at the end it gives exact match.
For some it works with space and for some it works without space why its so unexpected and how to handle in azure or MVC application ?

Note:
I have uploaded index documents from azure sql database, I checked in database there is not space at the end of "Bob Johnson".

Comment: Are you referring specifically to Azure Search service? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I 'm referring Azure search service, I have edited my question

Comment: This behavior is unexpected. Are you using a custom analyzer? The default lexical analysis removes whitespaces in Azure Search. Are you using a Search API? Feel free to contact me at nateko _AT_ Microsoft _DOT_ com.

Comment: No I 'm not using any custom analyzer

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Search, the standard analyzer used by default and the language specific analyzers discards spaces during lexical analysis both at indexing and query time. The search query with added space should not return different results. If you are still experiencing the behavior, please contact me via the email address left in the comment with the service and index names. I will take a close look. Thanks.

Nate